# Angular: List / Form module

Tags: angular

I'm a newcomer at Angular.

I need to build a Frontend application to work with a list of records (View list + CRUD) using Angular 12.

According to my vision I need 2 parts in my app:

- List - generates a list to view list of records
- Form - generates a form to create, read and update a record

So I have a couple of questions:

**1. MODULES vs COMPONENTS**

Shall I use 1 module and split the logic into several components **OR** shall I create 2 modules (List Module and Form Module)?

**2. GLOBAL LOGIC**

I need a global logic which will manipulate with parts of the application.

Based upon some parameters the logic shall execute the 1st or the 2nd part of the application.

Can you share some examples how to organize such logic in Angular?

Comment: First create, then look at optimizing stuff. Premature optimization won't give you much benefits. Example, you might install 2 libraries for UI components.

Comment: Found a nice tutorial here:
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good article from the Angular team: [Guidelines for creating NgModules](https://angular.io/guide/module-types#guidelines-for-creating-ngmodules). It is a good article by itself and considering most developers use the official documentation as the main guidance, there is a good chance your team members would be familiar with this and would be able to pick things up quickly.

Comment: I'm afraid you provided a wrong URL from your buffer :)